# beamer: Change font color for citation in footnote with biblatex phys style

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footer, fullcite

I am trying to change the font color (all text, with possible customization for author, journal, etc fields) for in-frame citations on a beamer template with biblatex style=phys. Here is the MWE producing the error

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[style=phys,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
condition\footnote[frame]{\fullcite{farhi00}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and here is refs.bib

```
@article{farhi00,
    title = {Quantum {Computation} by {Adiabatic} {Evolution}},
    journal = {arXiv:quant-ph/0001106},
    author = {Farhi, Edward and Goldstone, Jeffrey and Gutmann, Sam and Sipser, Michael},
    month = jan,
    year = {2000}}
```

which yields

[image]

I tried many approaches for changing the text color at the bottom, including using the hyperref package as well as many different suggested renewcommands. I am able to change the marker color for the footnote but not the text color. Any tips? I am open to using something other than `footnote[frame]{\fullcite{}}` but when I tried to use `\footcite{}` nothing showed up at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You can change the colours via `\setbeamercolor{bibliography ...}{...}`:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[style=phys,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{farhi00,
    title = {Quantum {Computation} by {Adiabatic} {Evolution}},
    journal = {arXiv:quant-ph/0001106},
    author = {Farhi, Edward and Goldstone, Jeffrey and Gutmann, Sam and Sipser, Michael},
    month = jan,
    year = {2000}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry title}{fg=blue!50!cyan}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry author}{fg=violet}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry location}{fg=green}
\setbeamercolor{bibliography entry note}{fg=orange}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
condition\footnote[frame]{\fullcite{farhi00}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: @jamessud You're welcome!